# Sign Up form and Sign In form not redirecting to the Same Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am having a little issue, i just manually configured a user authentication process and added a profile to the user through a one to one relationship. All this is working fine but i have this weird problem of the sign-in  and sing-up forms not redirecting to the same page. The sing-up page redirects to the user profile `/users/:user_id/profile` while the sign-in form redirects to `/users/:user_id`,both link are working as they are both supported by my routes file. I would like both to redirect to the same page `/users/:user_id/profile`.

My Controllers

**Create Action in Users Controller**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the app"
    redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile)
  else
    flash[:error_message] 
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This method works well and redirects to `/users/:user_id/profile` from the sign-up form.

**Create action in Sessions Controller**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     sign_in user
     redirect_back_or_to user
  else
     flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email / password combination'
     render 'new'
  end
```

The Sessions create method works and redirects to `/users/:user_id` but when the line `redirect_back_or_to user`is changed to `redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile)`, it throws the error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :user_id=>nil, :format=>nil}`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Change all instances of `user` to `@user` in the `create` action of the `SessionsController`.

Comment: Thanks @ptd, but basically what is the major difference between `user` and `@user`?

Comment: `@user` gets passed to your view. So if you don't need that, you can also change `redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile)` to `redirect_to user_profile_path(user, @profile)`. The key is that you were using a variable you never defined.